# Enviar variables $_POST[] con header("location: URL");

Tags: php, html

Tengo un archivo PHP en el que voy enviando las acciones con formularios en los que hay inputs type hidden con las variables que necesito. Pero llega un momento en el que necesito recargar la página y conservar las variables del `$_POST`. La recarga es necesaria para evitar el reenvio de formulario.

Como podría hacer algo así? JavaScript tal vez? o hay alguna manera de hacerlo con PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar `sesiones` para utilizar variables globales a tu programa, estas serán comunes en todos tus ficheros, persistiendo hasta cerrar la sesión.

De esta manera no necesitas pasar parámetros mediante GET/POST, pudiendo redireccionar mediante `header()` sin perder datos guardados en variables de sesión.

```html
<!-- method POST -->
<input type="hidden" title="nombre usuario" name="usuario">
```

```php
// Se abre una sesión.
session_start();
$miarray = $_REQUEST['usuario'];

$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

// Ya puedes redirigir.
header("location: ....")

// En otro fichero o en el mismo:
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) {
    echo "has logeado con el usuario temporal ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
}
// Se cierra sesión (de manera controlada).
session_destroy();
```

O una [cookie PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp):

```php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

Comment: No quiero guardar esa variable en la sesion, ya que es solo para una función puntual, en la que necesito dos variables.

Comment: Una cookie de JavaScript puede ayudar en este caso.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de eso? (no soy muy bueno en javascript) gracias.

Comment: Puse en PHP otro snippet, si quieres cambiar a JS por alguna razón de peso, [aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) se explica como, si necesitas mayor explicación puedo poner un snippet, pero sería casi copiar y pegar. Es sencillo.